# What is the most dense object in the universe?

Tags: universe, density

Inspired by this answer to the question, [Why is the Sun's density less than the inner planets?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/14891/11851), what is the most dense object in the universe?

Comment: Are you excluding singularities?

Comment: A singularity isn't observable and may or may not exist.

Comment: I'd say Trump would be in the top 3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let us define this as the largest *observable* density of a stable object, in order to exclude black holes which may have  a very large (infinite) density at their centers or objects collapsing towards a black hole status.

If we restrict the definition in this way, then the answer should be the core of the most massive neutron star that we know about.

At present there are a couple of neutron stars with mass of about $2M_{\odot}$ ([Demorest et al. 2010](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.5788); [Antoniadis et al. 2013](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6875). Depending on the exact composition and equation of state at their centres these should have densities of around $2 \times 10^{18}$ kg/m$^{3}$ at their centers and average densities of $\sim 10^{18}$ kg/m$^3$.

Note that these densities are around 3 times the density of a proton or neutron or 5-10 times the density of nuclei at zero pressure.

In principle, the density of a single electron is much higher.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39957/discussion-on-answer-by-rob-jeffries-what-is-the-most-dense-object-in-the-univer).